Why is the Drawable on the TextInputLayout not clearly visible?
I am trying to add a microphone button to a text field so that users can speak which will be translated to text.
My layout looks as below:
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/descriptionLayout"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/volunteering_description"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/projectLayout"
        app:endIconMode="custom"
        app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_microphone"
        app:endIconContentDescription="Voice Input"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/etDescription"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minLines="2" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


The icon appears well like black and white when viewed independently, but when added in the TextInputLayout, it gets grayed out and not clearly visible:

I have tried app:boxBackgroundMode="none" which didn't help either.
Does anyone have suggestion how to fix it?
The original icon can be found via this link.

Welcome to stackoverflow! If you found an answer useful, you can mark it as accepted answer by clicking the checkmark at the left side of an answer.

I could not reproduce the issue using your exact code, so there might be something wrong with the drawable you created. Please try to create your drawable like this:
Right-click on the res folder in Android Studio and choose New -> Image Asset

Then, switch to the "Action Bar and Tab Icons" tab on the top:
[
Finally, choose keyboard voice as clipart and click Next -> Create:

Overwrite any current files. Then, the output should look like this:

